# Processing an array of objects with multithreading - invalid use of void expression error

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading

I need to run some number of threads to process an array of objects.

So I've written this piece of code :

```
unsigned int object_counter = 0;
while(object_counter != (obj_max - left))
{
    thread genThread[thread_num];//create thread objects

    ///launch threads
    int thread_index = 0;
    for (; thread_index<thread_num; thread_index++)
    {
        genThread[thread_index] = thread(object[object_counter].gen_maps());//launch a thread

        object_counter++;
        if(object_counter == (obj_max - left)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    ///finish threads
    for (; thread_index>0; thread_index--)
    {
        genThread[thread_index].join();

    }
}
```

Basically, there is an array of objects (number of objects = `obj_max - left`). 
Each object has a function (void type function) called `gen_maps()` that generates a terrain.

What I want to do is running all `gen_maps()` functions from all objects using multithreading.

A maximum number of threads is stored in `thread_num` variable.

But when I'm trying to compile this code I'm getting an error:

```
error: invalid use of void expression
         genThread[thread_index] = thread(object[object_counter].gen_maps(), thread_index);//launch a thread
                                                                                         ^
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more extendable way to manage an arbitrarily large number of jobs with a smaller number of threads is to use a thread pool.

Here's a naive implementation (for better efficiency there would be 2 condition variables to manage control and state reporting) which allows the initiator to add an arbitrary number of jobs or threads and wait for all jobs to be complete.

```
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <deque>
#include <cassert>
#include <ciso646>
#include <iostream>

struct work_pool
{
    std::mutex control_mutex;
    std::condition_variable control_cv;
    std::deque<std::function<void()>> jobs;
    bool terminating = false;
    std::size_t running = 0;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    work_pool(std::size_t n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
    {
        add_threads(n);
    }

    work_pool(const work_pool&) = delete;
    work_pool& operator=(const work_pool&) = delete;

    ~work_pool()
    {
        wait();
        shutdown();
    }


    void add_threads(std::size_t n)
    {
        while (n--)
        {
            threads.emplace_back([this]{
                run_jobs();
            });
        }
    }

    void run_jobs()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            auto lock = std::unique_lock(control_mutex);
            control_cv.wait(lock, [this] {
                return terminating or not jobs.empty();
            });

            if (terminating) return;

            ++running;

            auto job = std::move(jobs.front());
            jobs.pop_front();

            lock.unlock();

            job();

            lock.lock();

            --running;

            lock.unlock();

            control_cv.notify_one();
        }
    }

    void shutdown()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(control_mutex);
        terminating = true;
        lock.unlock();
        control_cv.notify_all();
        for (auto&& t : threads) {
            if (t.joinable()) {
                t.join();
            }
        }

        threads.clear();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(control_mutex);
        control_cv.wait(lock, [this] {
            return jobs.empty() and not running;
        });
    }

    template<class F>
    void add_work(F&& f)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(control_mutex);
        assert(not terminating);
        jobs.emplace_back(std::forward<F>(f));
        lock.unlock();
        control_cv.notify_all();
    }
};

// dummy function for exposition
void generate_map() {}

int main()
{
    work_pool pool;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; ++i)
        pool.add_work(generate_map);

    pool.wait();

    // maps are now all generated

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `object[object_counter].gen_maps()` you *call* the function `gen_maps` and use the returned value as the thread function. Apparently `gen_maps` is declared to return `void` which leads to the error you get.

You need to pass a pointer to the function, and then pass the object it should be called on as an argument to the thread:

```
thread(&SomeClass::gen_maps, object[object_counter])
```